# Using Grad and NDSolve with vector variables

Tags: differential-equations, vector, vector-calculus

A simple orbital model might be developed like this:

```
day = 86400;
G=6.67408*10^-11;
ER=6367440;
earthmass=5.9722*10^24;

pot[{x_, y_, z_}] := -G earthmass / Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2];
grad = -Grad[pot[{x[t], y[t], z[t]}], {x[t], y[t], z[t]}];
odesys = { {x[0], y[0], z[0]} == {1.1 ER, 0, 0}, {x'[0], y'[0], 
     z'[0]} == 
    RotationTransform[ 
      98 \[Degree], {1, 0, 0}]@(7543.7 {0, 1, 0}), {x''[t], y''[t], 
     z''[t]} == grad} ;
soln = NDSolve[odesys, {x, y, z}, {t, 0, 5 day} ];
```

And that works just fine:

```
Show[ { 
  Graphics3D[ {Opacity[0.5], Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, ER]}],
  ParametricPlot3D[{x[t], y[t], z[t]} /. soln, {t, 0, 5 day}, 
   PlotRange -> Table[{-2 ER, 2 ER}, 3], AspectRatio -> Automatic]
  }
 ]
```

[image: gradient orbital]

But what I would like to do is just use the variables as vectors, something like:

```
odesys = {x[0] == {1.1 ER, 0, 0}, x'[0] == {0, 7534, 0}, 
  x''[t] == -earthmass Norm[x[t]]^-2 G Normalize[x[t]]}
```

which works

```
NDSolve[odesys, x, {t, 0, 5 day}]
```

But I'm not sure how to go about getting Grad to take a variable and make the assumption that it is a 3-element vector. How should I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a perfect answer, but requires less manual analysis compared to yours. Notice that `Grad` can be replaced with `D`:

```
Grad[f[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] == D[f[x, y, z], {{x, y, z}}]
(* True *)
```

and `D` works partly correctly when we use an implicit array as 2nd argument:

```
D[vector.vector, {vector}] /. vector -> {x, y, z}
(* 1.{x, y, z} + {x, y, z}.1 *)
```

To amend this, we introduce a replace rule:

```
rule = Dot[a___, 1, b___] :> Dot[a, IdentityMatrix[3], b];

odesys = {x[0] == {1.1 ER, 0, 0}, x'[0] == {0, 7534, 0}, 
   x''[t] == D[G earthmass/Sqrt[x[t].x[t]], {x[t]}]} /. rule

solnvector = NDSolve[odesys, x, {t, 0, 5 day}][[1]]

With[{x = x /. solnvector}, 
 Animate[Show[{Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5], Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, ER], Red, PointSize@Large, 
        Point@x[t]}], #}], {t, 0, 5 day}] &@ParametricPlot3D[x[t], {t, 0, 5 day}]]
```

[image]